# Flip image vertical 3D css

Tags: html, css

Basic HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="im-fix"><img src="foo.jpg"></div>
     <div class="img-closed"><img src="foo-close.jpg"></div>
     <div class="img-open"><img src="foo-open.jpg"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

With that I have a basic image on screen, what I need to do is to mimic the opening of an envelop using css3
my CSS is something like this:

```
.img-closed {
    position: absolute;bottom: 163px;
    transition:width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}
.img-open:hover {
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0);
}
```

But all I got is something like sniping wheel I don't want that, I want it to "open up" and when it open it shows the inside with different information..

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) is a good place to start.
1. Flip the axis with `rotateX`.
2. `transform` origin over half the height.
(at the end you need to rotate the card the other way.)

Comments also include a useful cross-browser discussion.